# How to hide an Admin account on the Windows 7 logon screen

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is it possible to hide an Admin account on the Windows 7 logon screen?
If so, how would I do it?

I am doing some business work on my machine and my kids need to use the same system.

So, I need my machine to only show one user account on the welcome screen. I need to hide my Admin account.

Answer (score 4):

Open `regedit.exe`, go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
```

On Windows 7 the two last keys `SpecialAccounts` and `UserList` may not exist and you will have to create them.

Under `UserList`, create a new 32-bit DWORD value and name it with the user Login, set value to 0.

Create a new 32-bit DWORD value for each user, in case you have more.

Thats it.

In the case the user is still being displayed, open `secpol.msc`, go to `Local Policies\Security Settings`, find the entry `Interactive Logon: Hide last user` and switch it to Activated.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Windows Registry

```
Start Button -> Type Regedit -> Press Enter
```

Browse to:

```
HKEY_Local_Machine
    SOFTWARE\
        Microsoft\
            Windows NT\
                CurrentVersion\
                    Winlogon\
                        SpecialAccounts\
                            UserList
```

Right Click:

```
UserList
    Choose New
        select DWORD (32-bit) Value
```

Enter Names:

```
Enter the name of the account you wish to hide from the Welcome Screen

Repeat for additional names you wish to hide
```